# compare 2 2D lists and delete items from one list based on another

Tags: python, list, 2d, delete-row

I have two 2D lists that look like this:

```
list1 = [[26, "k", 5.78],
         [26, "M", 5.89],
         [26, "J", 7.89],
          .........
         [290, "O", 9.9]]
```

`len(list1)` = 4978

```
list2 = [[26, "k", 0.99],
         [26, "M", 0.88],
         [26, "J", 9.77],
           .......
         [290, "O", 7.88]]
```

`len(list2)` =4765

I want to iterate through list1 and if one row's first index and second index is not in list2, I want to delete this row.

Essentially, it's something like this:

```
for i in list1:
    if i[0]+i[1] not in any rows of list2, delete this row from list1.
```

for example, if list1 has a row like this:

```
[57, "k", 9.8]
```

but in list2, there is no row that contains `57, and "k"`, then I need to delete this row from list1.

the third column in both list1 and list2 is not involved in this comparison. 
And also, it's guaranteed that for every row in list2, there is another row in list1 that contains corresponding first element and second element, meaning that, if list2 has a row like:

```
[58, "J", 0.9]
```

Then, list1 definitely has a row starting with `58, and "J"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
list1 = [[26, "k", 5.78],
     [26, "M", 5.89],
     [26, "J", 7.89],
     [290, "O", 9.9]]

list2 = [[26, "k", 0.99],
     [26, "M", 0.88],
     [26, "J", 9.77],
     [290, "O", 7.88]]
new_list1 = [[a, b, c] for a, b, c in list1 if any(a == d and b == e for d, e, f in list2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = [[26, "k", 5.78],
         [26, "M", 5.89],
         [26, "J", 7.89],
         [26, "K", 7.89],  # will be removed
         [290, "O", 9.9]]

list2 = [[26, "k", 0.99],
         [26, "M", 0.88],
         [26, "J", 9.77],
         [290, "O", 7.88]]

list2_indices = set([(elem[0], elem[1]) for elem in list2])
list1 = [elem for elem in list1 if (elem[0], elem[1]) in list2_indices]
print(list1)
```

It first creates a set of all first and second elements in element two.
After that, it creates a new list with all elements of list1 that have the indices in list2.

Instead of creating a new list, it is also possible to remove the items from list1 if it needs to be in-place.

Comment: `set([(elem[0], elem[1]) for elem in list2])` -> `{(a,b) for a,b,_ in list2}`